# how to get clicked element while using "select all" operator i.e " * " using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('body').on("click", "*", function(e) {
      console.log("clicked tag:" + this.tagName);
      console.log("index:(" + this.tagName + ")[" + $(this).index(this.tagName) + "]");
      });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>hello !</p>
    <div>
      <p>stack overflow</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This code identifies the **click event** and gets the **html tag** clicked by the person and also displays the **index** of the element. The problem is that it first returns the **html tag of the clicked element(which is required)** and then after that it **also returns the parent element as well(which is not required)**. I only want the clicked element, not the parent element.  How am i supposed to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using the `*` selector, when you click on an element, it's propagating and triggering the `click` handler for every ancestor on the way up to the `body`. You could just use `evt.stopPropagation()`, but there's no need because what you want is already available via `evt.target` (ie. the element that triggered the click handler bound to the `body`):

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'click', function( evt ) {
  console.log( evt.target );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you `evt.stopPropagation()`  gave me the desired result.